# how do I wire a duplex outlet that will always be hot from a switch outlet combo?

Tags: electrical

I have a combo switch outlet that has one hot outlet and the switch controls a floodlight over my pool.

I want to add a duplex outlet further down my patio to be able to plug in my aerator pump and ceiling heat lamp. This outlet needs to be hot and not affected by the switch.

A diagram would really be helpful also. Thank you, Harr.

Comment: Is the outlet on the combo always hot?

Comment: Yes the out let is always hot

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to tap off the wiring for the existing outlet using pigtails (short pieces of wire of the same weight and color).

Run a new 14/2 cable from the combo box to the new outlet location. Remove the hot lead (probably black) from the side of the existing outlet. Connect that lead to the black of the new cable and to the black pigtail using a wire nut or a push-in connector. Attach the other end of the black pigtail back on the hot terminal of the combo outlet.

If the hot wire to the combo outlet is already connected through a wire nut, you just have to add the new black to that bundle and reattach the wire nut (or a bigger one if necessary), no new pigtail needed.

Do the same for the neutral (white) wires. White to white.

Connect all ground wires (bare or green).

Comment: Thank you bib. I will attempt this first thing in the morning. Thanks  Harry

Comment: Be sure to turn off the power to the outlet and confirm with a tester.

Comment: Just make sure to use an outdoor rated cable (not NM!) for this!

Comment: Also, outlets within 20 ft. of a pool need to be GFCI. The simplest way to do this may be to replace the current circuit breaker with a GFCI version